# How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS without rooting the device in Android

Tags: android, authentication, google-cloud-platform

I'm developing an Android application which has to authenticate against Google Cloud services, for which I need to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. I've found that it is necessary to root the device to do that. My question is if it should be possible to set such variable without rooting the it.
Regards,
Manuel Heras

I've look at meny forums wih¡th no success and I expect someone can help me to do what is mentioned in the title of this post.

Comment: Why do you need to use a service account? Normally, you would implement Google OAuth.